# Vert.x performance drop when starting with -cluster option

Tags: java, hazelcast, vert.x

I'm wondering if any one experienced the same problem.

We have a Vert.x application and in the end it's purpose is to insert 600 million rows into a Cassandra cluster. We are testing the speed of Vert.x in combination with Cassandra by doing tests in smaller amounts.

If we run the fat jar (build with Shade plugin) without the -cluster option, we are able to insert 10 million records in about a minute. When we add the -cluster option (eventually we will run the Vert.x application in cluster) it takes about 5 minutes for 10 million records to insert.

Does anyone know why?

We know that the Hazelcast config will create some overhead, but never thought it would be 5 times slower. This implies we will need 5 EC2 instances in cluster to get the same result when using 1 EC2 without the cluster option.

As mentioned, everything runs on EC2 instances:

- 2 Cassandra servers on t2.small
- 1 Vert.x server on t2.2xlarge

Comment: Can you give some details about your app architecture? E.g. how it uses the event bus?

Comment: hi @tsegismont, we have a sender verticle (1 instance) which puts Json serialised POJO objects (3 primitive members) on the eventbus using send() in a loop. This loop is a Intstream loop which runs with the parallel option.

On the other side there is receiver verticle (8 instances) that handles the incoming messages from the eventbus. We decocde the serialized Json back to the POJO and insert the object into the cassandra cluster using a prepared statement.

I'll update the question to include the code we use in this test project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are actually running into corner cases of the Vert.x Hazelcast Cluster manager.

First of all you are using a worker Verticle to send your messages (30000001). Under the hood Hazelcast is blocking and thus when you send a message from a worker the version 3.3.3 does not take that in account. Recently we added this fix https://github.com/vert-x3/issues/issues/75 (not present in 3.4.0.Beta1 but present in 3.4.0-SNAPSHOTS) that will improve this case.

Second when you send all your messages at the same time, it runs into another corner case that prevents the Hazelcast cluster manager to use a cache of the cluster topology. This topology cache is usually updated after the first message has been sent and sending all the messages in one shot prevents the usage of the ache (short explanation HazelcastAsyncMultiMap#getInProgressCount will be > 0 and prevents the cache to be used), hence paying the penalty of an expensive lookup (hence the cache).

If I use Bertjan's reproducer with 3.4.0-SNAPSHOT + Hazelcast and the following change: send message to destination, wait for reply. Upon reply send all messages then I get a lot of improvements.

Without clustering : 5852 ms
With clustering with HZ 3.3.3 :16745 ms
With clustering with HZ 3.4.0-SNAPSHOT + initial message : 8609 ms

I believe also you should not use a worker verticle to send that many messages and instead send them using an event loop verticle via batches. Perhaps you should explain your use case and we can think about the best way to solve it.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate explanation Julien! 
Agreed that this is a special case. Use case is to read a BIG chunk of information (hundreds of millions of records) and put each record on the eventbus to be processed by a verticle. Sending in batches is a good idea since this will allow the scheduler to handle other events in between batches (receiving and processing messages, e.g.). Another option could be to condense the number of messages (for example, put the information of 10 messages in 1 message). 
The fix in 3.4.0-SNAPSHOT looks like a good improvement, I'll pass this on to the team.

Comment: Things to try out:
- send in batches to allow for some processing between sending messages
- try 3.4.0-SNAPSHOT
- coarser granularity of messages by bundling information in messages
- sending from an eventloop verticle instead of a worker verticle
- experiment with different cluster managers (JGroups instead of Hazelcast)

Answer (score 3):

When you're you enable clustering (of any kind) to an application you are making your application more resilient to failures but you're also adding a performance penalty.

For example your current flow (without clustering) is something like:

```
client -> 
  vert.x app -> 
    in memory same process eventbus (negletible) ->
    handler -> cassandra
  <- vert.x app
<- client
```

Once you enable clustering:

```
client ->
  vert.x app ->
    serialize request ->
      network request cluster member ->
        deserialize request ->
          handler -> cassandra
        <- serialize response
      <- network reply
    <- deserialize response
  <- vert.x app
<- client
```

As you can see there are many encode decode operations required plus several network calls and this all gets added to your total request time.

In order to achive best performance you need to take advantage of locality the closer you are of your data store usually the fastest.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add the code of the project. I guess that would help.

Sender verticle:

```
public class ProviderVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

    @Override
    public void start() throws Exception {
        IntStream.range(1, 30000001).parallel().forEach(i -> {
        vertx.eventBus().send("clustertest1", Json.encode(new TestCluster1(i, "abc", LocalDateTime.now())));
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() throws Exception {
        super.stop();
   }
}
```

And the inserter verticle

```
public class ReceiverVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

    private int messagesReceived = 1;

    private Session cassandraSession;

    @Override
    public void start() throws Exception {

        PoolingOptions poolingOptions = new PoolingOptions()
                .setCoreConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.LOCAL, 2)
                .setMaxConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.LOCAL, 3)
                .setCoreConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.REMOTE, 1)
                .setMaxConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.REMOTE, 3)
                .setMaxRequestsPerConnection(HostDistance.LOCAL, 20)
                .setMaxQueueSize(32768)
                .setMaxRequestsPerConnection(HostDistance.REMOTE, 20);

        Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder()
                .withPoolingOptions(poolingOptions)
                .addContactPoints(ClusterSetup.SEEDS)
                .build();

        System.out.println("Connecting session");
        cassandraSession = cluster.connect("kiespees");
        System.out.println("Session connected:\n\tcluster [" + cassandraSession.getCluster().getClusterName() + "]");
        System.out.println("Connected hosts: ");

        cassandraSession.getState().getConnectedHosts().forEach(host -> System.out.println(host.getAddress()));

        PreparedStatement prepared = cassandraSession.prepare(
                "insert into clustertest1 (id, value, created) " +
                        "values (:id, :value, :created)");

        PreparedStatement preparedTimer = cassandraSession.prepare(
                "insert into timer (name, created_on, amount) " +
                        "values (:name, :createdOn, :amount)");

        BoundStatement timerStart = preparedTimer.bind()
                .setString("name", "clusterteststart")
                .setInt("amount", 0)
                .setTimestamp("createdOn", new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));
        cassandraSession.executeAsync(timerStart);

        EventBus bus = vertx.eventBus();

        System.out.println("Bus info: " + bus.toString());
        MessageConsumer<String> cons = bus.consumer("clustertest1");
        System.out.println("Consumer info: " + cons.address());

        System.out.println("Waiting for messages");

        cons.handler(message -> {
            TestCluster1 tc = Json.decodeValue(message.body(), TestCluster1.class);

            if (messagesReceived % 100000 == 0)
                System.out.println("Message received: " + messagesReceived);

            BoundStatement boundRecord = prepared.bind()
                    .setInt("id", tc.getId())
                    .setString("value", tc.getValue())
                    .setTimestamp("created", new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));
            cassandraSession.executeAsync(boundRecord);

            if (messagesReceived % 100000 == 0) {
                BoundStatement timerStop = preparedTimer.bind()
                        .setString("name", "clusterteststop")
                        .setInt("amount", messagesReceived)
                        .setTimestamp("createdOn", new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));
                cassandraSession.executeAsync(timerStop);
            }

            messagesReceived++;
            //message.reply("OK");
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() throws Exception {
        super.stop();
        cassandraSession.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I was onsite with Bjorn today and couldn't quite wrap my head around the difference in throughput between clustered and non clustered mode. Let's hope we're missing something obvious ;-) I've created a runnable reproducer: https://github.com/bertjan/vertx-cluster-performance See the README for more information.

Comment: JGroupsClusterManager seems to be faster than the default Hazelcast cluster manager. IgniteClusterManager too, but not faster than JGroups. See 'findings' in the README.

Comment: Discussion moved to the Google group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vertx-dev/Z0v8e6TPrqw